# How can I properly initialize the needed vectors in a Neural Network Model?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a Neural Network Model from scratch in Python (using Numpy). For reference, I'm using the Chapter e-7 of [this book](https://work.caltech.edu/textbook.html) (Learning from data, by Professor Abu-Mostafa) as a theoretical support.

One of the first problems that I'm facing is how to correctly initialize the matrix of weights and the vectors of inputs and outputs (W, x and s, respectively).

Here is the my approach:

- Let `L` be the number of layers (you do not count the 'first' layer; i.e., the layer of the vector x plus 'bias').
- Let `d` be the dimension of the hidden layers (I'm assuming that all hidden layers have the same number of nodes).
- Let `out` be the number of nodes at the last layer (it is typically 1).

Now, here is how I defined the matrix and vectors of interest:

- Let `w_` be the vector of weights. Actually, it is a vector in which each component is a matrix the of the form W_{L}. Here, the (i, j)-th value is the w_{i, j}^{(L)} term.
- Let `x_` be the vector of inputs.
- Let `s_` be the vector of outputs; you may see `s_` as `numpy.dot(W^{L}.T, x^{L-1})`.

The following image summarizes what I've just described:

[image: A pair of nodes with the proper notation for each component.]

The problem arises from the fact that the dimensions of each layer (input, hidden layers and output) are NOT the same. What I was trying to do is to split each vector into different variables; however, work with it in the following steps of the algorithm is extremely difficult (because of how the indexes become a mess). Here is the piece of code that replicates my attempt:

```
class NeuralNetwork:
    """
    Neural Network Model
    """
    def __init__(self, L, d, out):
        self.L = L # number of layers
        self.d = d # dimension of hidden layers
        self.out = out # dimension of the output layer

    def initialize_(self, X): 
        # Initialize the vector of inputs
        self.x_ = np.zeros((self.L - 1) * (self.d + 1)).reshape(self.L - 1, self.d + 1)
        self.xOUT_ = np.zeros(1 * self.out).reshape(1, self.out)

        # Initialize the vector of outputs
        self.s_ = np.zeros((self.L - 1) * (self.d)).reshape(self.L - 1, self.d)
        self.sOUT_ = np.zeros(1 * self.out).reshape(1, self.out)

        # Initialize the vector of weights
        self.wIN_  = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1 * (X.shape[1] + 1) * self.d).reshape(1, X.shape[1] + 1, self.d)
        self.w_ = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, (self.L - 2) * (self.d + 1) * self.d).reshape(self.L - 2, self.d + 1, self.d)
        self.wOUT_ = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1 * (self.d + 1) * self.out).reshape(1, self.d + 1, self.out) 

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.initialize_(X)
```

Whenever `IN` or `OUT` appear in the code, that is my way to deal with the differences of dimension between the input and output layers, respectively.

Clearly, this is NOT a good way to do it. So my question is: How can I work with these different dimensional vectors (with respect to each layer) in a clever way?

For example, after initialize them, I want to reproduce the following algorithm (forward-propagation) - you will see that, with my way to index things, it becomes almost impossible:

[image: Forward Propagation Algorithm]

Where \theta(s) = \tanh(s).

P.S.: I also tried to create an array of arrays (or an array of list), but if I do that, my indexes become useless - they do not represent anymore what I wanted them to represent.

Comment: Btw there is no need in `reshaping` your arrays, e.g. `np.zeros(1 * self.out).reshape(1, self.out)` can be replaced with `np.zeros((1, self.out))` etc. This will make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encapsulate the neuron logic and let the neurons perform the calculations individually:

```
class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, I, O, b):
        self.I = I # input neurons from previous layer
        self.O = O # output neurons in next layer
        self.b = b # bias

    def activate(self, X):
        output = np.dot(self.I, X) + self.b
        ...
        return theta(output)
```